# Xamarin Android - Stretch ImageView to fit parent without resizing parent

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, layout, scaling

I have the following, seemingly taboo, goal: to fit an image as a background to a View.
This is a demonstration of what the goal is:

Demo：
[image: goal]

**Now here are the many scenarios I've tried and their undesired results**

#### Setting the background property to my drawable

Incredibly, Android (or Xamarin) decides that if a View's background is a drawable, *the view should expand its bounds if they are smaller than the background drawable's bounds!* It also disregards the image's aspect ratio and comes up with what appears to be an entirely random, new ratio to use.

Attempts 1:
[image: attemps1]
As you can see, as a background, the drawable destroys the parent View's dimensions. I could not find any options for controlling the background drawable's behavior, so I tried something different.

#### Using a FrameLayout and ImageView

Here are some of the attempts I have made with this setup. Green marks changes from one attempt to the next.

Attempts 2:
[image: attemps2]

Attempts 3:
[image: attemps3]

Attempts 4:
[image: attemps4]

Attempts 5:
[image: attemps5]

Attempts 6:
[image: attemps6]

**Basically, I've tried just about every combination of gravity, scaleType, adjustViewBounds, and width/height that I can think of for about 3 hours.**

Coming from the world of WPF, I'm amazed at how misleading and unintuitive the Android design platform is - which I'd be more okay with if it wasn't for the fact that there seems to be zero official documentation on the simple, commonplace goal I have here.

#### What am I doing wrong? How do I force the image to deform to its parent's bounds?

Here is the background image itself (also noted in Attempts 1): https://s17.postimg.org/n6ud0c2zj/ui_optionsactivity_titlebackground.png

*To note:
There are a million questions for scaling ImageViews whilst keeping the aspect ratio - this is *NOT* what I want! I want my ImageView to destroy its aspect ratio in order to stretch to fit whatever bounds it's given.*

Comment: Hi, can you attach your background picture

Comment: Yes, this is the raw image: [https://s17.postimg.org/n6ud0c2zj/ui_optionsactivity_titlebackground.png](https://s17.postimg.org/n6ud0c2zj/ui_optionsactivity_titlebackground.png)